# What does the "two periods" operator mean in the context of a subscript inside of square brackets?

Tags: rust, syntax

I was looking through Rust's source code to better acquaint myself with the language. I came across this snippet.

```
// Collect program arguments as a Vec<String>.
let cmd: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();

// Some unrelated code omitted here.

match subcommand::parse_name(&cmd[1][..]) {
    // It did some stuff here.
}
```

I didn't understand the `[..]`. So, I went and checked out the declaration of `parse_name`:

```
pub fn parse_name(name: &str) -> Option<Box<Subcommand>>
```

It's what I expected, but I still don't get the `[..]`. What does it mean in this context? Isn't it just passing the first `String` in `cmd` as a `&str`? If so, is this equivalent to just writing `cmd[1]`? Why did they do it this way?

Answer (score 27):

Two periods (`..`) is the *range operator*. You can find this in the [Operators and Symbols Appendix](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) of the Rust book. There are six flavors:

1. [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html): `1..10`
2. [`RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html): `1..`
3. [`RangeTo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeTo.html): `..10`
4. [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html): `..`
5. [`RangeInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeToInclusive.html): `1..=10`
6. [`RangeToInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeToInclusive.html): `..=10`

When no item occupies an end position, the range goes on "forever" in that direction.

This combines with the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait (or [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html), if mutation is required). In your example, you have a string slice (kind of, see next point) that you are applying indexing to: `"foo"[2..]`.

Specifically, `&str` implements `Index` as

> Returns a slice of the given string from the byte range

Then there's a *third* bit of ergonomics happening: [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) (or [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) in similar cases). [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) implements `Deref` by returning a `&str`, so any method available to a `&str` is available to a `String`.

Answer (score 12):

This is just a way to explicitly coerce from `String` to `&str`. In this case, the `[..]` is actually unnecessary as `Deref` coercions means that `parse_name(&args[1])` is valid too: `&String` will borrow to `&str` implicitly.

The `[ ]` indexing operator is calling the [`std::ops::Index`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait, and the `..` syntax is creating [a `std::ops::RangeFull` value](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html). `cmd` is a `Vec<String>`, since `std::env::args()` returns [an `Iterator` over `String`s](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/struct.Args.html).

Hence, the `foo[..]` syntax is calling the implementation of `Index<RangeFull>` for `String` (which you can see in the list of Implementors on the `Index` page). The [implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d877e6540431d99b0945a3d27eeb466b0d693902/src/libcollections/string.rs#L974-L981) looks like:

```
impl ops::Index<ops::RangeFull> for String {
    type Output = str;

    #[inline]
    fn index(&self, _index: ops::RangeFull) -> &str {
        unsafe { mem::transmute(&*self.vec) }
    }
}
```

The `&*self.vec` is borrowing the `String`'s internal `Vec<u8>` to `&[u8]`, and then the `transmute` is explicitly casting that to a `&str`, which is safe because `String`'s API ensures that the internal `Vec<u8>` is valid UTF-8, which is what `str` requires.

Comment: So in summary, `&cmd[1][..]` translates to English as "every character in the String at index 1 of `cmd` as a string slice"?

Comment: yep - that's accurate! "take a slice from the start of `cmd[1]` to the end of `cmd[1]`, inclusive"