# What is the ".." syntax inside a struct literal in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

From the [`std::default::Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) docs:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct SomeOptions {
    foo: i32,
    bar: f32,
}

fn main() {
    let options = SomeOptions { foo: 42, ..Default::default() };
}
```

What is the `..` prefix doing to the returned value of `Default::default()` and why is it necessary here? It almost seems like it's acting as a spread operator, but I'm not sure. I understand what `..Default::default()` is doing -- filling in the remaining struct parameters with the default values of `SomeOptions`, but not how `..` works. What is the name of this operator?

Comment: See also [What does the double-ellipsis operator mean in the context of a &str subscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31797599/155423) for information about another use of `..` in Rust.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is the [struct update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax). It is "needed" only to have a succinct way of moving / copying all of the members of a struct to a new one, potentially with some small modifications.

The "long" way of writing this would be:

```
let a = SomeOptions::default();
let options = SomeOptions { foo: 42, bar: a.bar };
```

You could indeed think of it similar to the JavaScript "spread" operator, but Rust's nuances of ownership and strong typing still come into play, so it's not as widely used. For example, you can't use this syntax to go between values of different types.

Comment: I've also seen initialization like this `let SomeOptions { foo: 42 .. } = SomeOptions::default();` which seems similar. Does anyone know what it does?

Comment: @Shabgard you have not seen that in real Rust code because it's [invalid Rust syntax](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c24d69bf55b4e8d9ffe777cc7ba9034a). If you meant `let SomeOptions { foo, .. } =`, then [Ignoring Remaining Parts of a Value with ..](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#ignoring-remaining-parts-of-a-value-with-)

Comment: Thank you. No, I don't think it's the case that you mentioned but it was also educating for me. [This piece of code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/ffedeab4f0097107240bec74cf376a79a5240181/runtime/parachains/src/scheduler.rs#L1587) is the exact instance of the usage that I had in mind.

Comment: @Shabgard that's exactly the syntax that I used in my comment; why do you think it's different?

Comment: Oh, I got confused because of the link you sent was pointing to this section "Ignoring Remaining Parts of a Value with .." which  was used inside a `match` block. But now that I studied the whole page it seems to be the case of [Destructuring Structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-to-break-apart-values). Now I understand it. Very helpful page anyway!